can't find crate for `alloc` in rust
rustc 1.84.0-nightly (662180b34 2024-10-20)
a minimal reproducible is here : minimal_reproducible
https://github.com/Horc-zh/-minimal_reproducible
I use the alloc crate in my lib.rs like this:
lib.rs:
#![no_std]
#![cfg_attr(test, no_main)]
#![feature(custom_test_frameworks)]
#![test_runner(crate::test_runner)]
#![reexport_test_harness_main = "test_main"]
#![feature(abi_x86_interrupt)]

extern crate alloc;
pub mod allocator;

But when I want to compile, the error occurs：
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `alloc`
 --> src\lib.rs:8:1
  |
8 | extern crate alloc;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate

There is my part of Cargo.toml:
[unstable]
build-std = ["core", "compiler_builtins", "alloc"]

Miraculously, allocator.rs did not report an error
use alloc::alloc::{GlobalAlloc, Layout};
use core::ptr::null_mut;

pub struct Dummy;

unsafe impl GlobalAlloc for Dummy {
    unsafe fn alloc(&self, layout: Layout) -> *mut u8 {
        null_mut()
    }

    unsafe fn dealloc(&self, ptr: *mut u8, layout: Layout) {
        panic!("dealloc should be never called")
    }
}

How can I fix this?

I've also asked on the Rust user forum

[unstable] is not a valid key in Cargo.toml! The excerpt you provided does compile otherwise. Please add a [mre]. (You can also probably remove most of the attributes from lib.rs as they are likely not necessary to reproduce the issue).

You've made the same error as in the linked question, [unstable] along with build-std goes in .cargo/config.toml not Cargo.toml!

Please not that a [mre] must be included within the question, not behind an external link.
